# how would server respond if a smb2 client issues a read request with more credits than it has?

Tags: smb

Lets take an example. A client has 10 credits, it sends 3 read request by charging 5 credits each. How will the server reply to these requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends the network and the server speed.
If the server issued the first request before the third request comes then it will be fine, but if not the server will send an RST. (The server will close the connection)

- The server has an inner credit counter, and if it lower than 0 the server assume that the client credit calculation is wrong , so the server close the connection, the client will reconnect to the server and the calcultion will start fresh.